# Query information based on Email from one from to another using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have 2 forms. The first form has a email  textbox and a button. The first form is connected to access database. The second form is also connected to access and contains multiple textboxes.

When the user types their email and clicks on the button in the first form. The application is supposed to query the information based on their email.

example: I type "Jeff@gmail.com" in first form click on button.

2nd form: based on "Jeff@gmail.com" the application queries the emails information in the texboxes in form 2 like age, hight, and weight.

How do I do this?

Comment: Try it first yourself. Get as far as you can. Then, when you have some actual code, come back here and post specific problems with the code.

Comment: Forms are just Classes; add whatever methods (or properties) to them that you need and provided you arent using default instances they can act as conduits for passing data.  There are hundreds, if not thousands, of similar questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Look up SQL SELECT statements and try as much as you can from there. Once you hit a snag post it here and I'll be happy to help